# Immediate login after successful registration on a plone site

Tags: authentication, plone, zope, z3c.form

I have a custom registration BrowserView where you have to extend some userdata (z3c.form with some fields including password). after successful saving these data i want the user to be logged in automaticaly and redirected to an other page in the site.

Thanks in advance for hints

Comment: Here are tips how to perform login in Python code: http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sessions/login.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So here's my working solution (thanks to mikko who pointed in the right direction):

1. authenticate your registration credentials in PAS

   ```
   member = portal.acl_users.authenticate(username, password, portal.REQUEST)
   ```
2. for redirects it's neccessary to set the authentication cookie. You can do this with "updateCredentials" (see pas/plugins/cookie_handler)

   ```
   if member:
       portal.acl_users.updateCredentials(portal.REQUEST, portal.REQUEST.RESPONSE, username, password)
   ```
3. redirect to the next page

   ```
   portal.REQUEST.RESPONSE.redirect(url)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend the userdata for new members, and add new fields to the registration form, it's probably best to extend the utility that provides the default userdata schema and to do it in such a way that you seamlessly hook into the existing registration machinery.

There is an example product **collective.examples.userdata** which you can use0 and extend for this purpose. It also has good documentation that explains to you all the necessary steps.

http://plone.org/products/collective.examples.userdata

Comment: That's not what petschki is asking; he's asking how, after a successful registration, the user can be logged in immediately.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not agree with the down vote. The stackoverflow's rule for down-voting says "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.". The "misunderstanding the question" doesn't seems to me neither sloppy nor (in this case) dangerous. A comment would suffice.